# How to connect to CometD server using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, streaming, cometd

I need to connect to a [CometD](http://cometd.org/) server using Objective-C from an iPhone, and stream data. What is the best way or is there a tutorial or tips?

Comment: This may be a good start ... [https://github.com/ddunkin/cometclient](https://github.com/ddunkin/cometclient)